# online file transfer between two user like skype/gtalk c#

Tags: c#

I want creating a online file transfer app. I would like the user to drag-drop an item into the file transfer application to initiate the file transfer just like skype or other messengers. can anyone give me good links or sample code for this

Answer (score 1):

One of the most complex part in the "peer-to-peer" data transfer is session initiation, since user can be hidden behind NAT, firewall or proxy server. You probably should take a look at [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) protocol for session initialization - it is used in many VoIP services. Some time ago I found [this SIP tutorial](http://voipmechanic.com/documents/sip_tutorial.pdf) rather descriptive, but there are many other docs.

Also, probably it would be useful to take a look at [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) protocol (GTalk is implemented with this protocol), there is [file transfer extension](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html).

Comment: hi ken thank you for reply. can you give me a good and simple link for this .By using this link i do that

Comment: You may take a look at list of XMPP libraries here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/. Particularly, one of C# implementations: http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/. BTW, I did not use it.

Answer (score 0):

[MSRP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4975) (Message Session Relay Protocol) is designed to send messages and files. It is used by
[SIMPLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE_(instant_messaging_protocol)) messaging systems. If might be worthwhile investigating.

Konnetic are the only provider of [MSRP .NET](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_msrp_sdk_std.aspx) solutions I know of.